# M-x org-plot/gnuplot gives "symbol's function definition is void: org-find-library-dir"

Tags: emacs, gnuplot

I was trying to use gnuplot from in Emacs to plot some data. The tutorial I was reading is [some official one](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-plot.html).

My gnuplot-mode has been installed thanks to [this nice tutorial](https://github.com/bruceravel/gnuplot-mode)

My emacs is v24, with Mac OS. Gnuplot is installed at `usr/bin/local/`

my Org mode is updated to 2013's version.

But I don't know what to do when the error

```
"symbol's function definition is void: org-find-library-dir"
```

appears when I attempt to run org-plot/gnuplot.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like an emacs error to me.  I've re-tagged it with `emacs`.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean? You mean it is a bug of emacs ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's a bug in *emacs* per-se -- But probably a bug in the package that interfaces emacs w/ gnuplot (either that, or a configuration error) -- I'm no elisp guru, so I don't know which ...

Answer (score 0):

I have this trouble also -- void function org-find-library-dir.

Finally I found the problem is that I load o-blog package earlier than org mode. o-blog depended on org-mode, and it require many org packages.

I believe your trouble is some thing similar, and you should adjust your init   file in order to load org-mode first.